# How to convert PHP String to PHP Regex

Tags: php

I am parsing the robots.txt.

```
Disallow: /?hl=*&*$
```

And converting str_replace string.

```
$my_regex = str_replace(array("?", "*", "/"), array("\?", "(.*)", "\/"), "/?hl=*&*$");
echo $my_regex;
```

And result

```
/?hl=*&*$
```

And I want result

```
\/\?hl=(.*)&(.*)$
```

I finding the this problem solution. pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that beginning with PHP 5.1.1, the backslash in double-quoted string literals should also be printed, so even your code should work fine with newer versions of PHP ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)).

Alternatively, consider using single quoted string literals with `'\?'` and `'\/'` so that the backslash was treated as a literal, and not part of an escape sequence (or even `'\\?'` and `'\\/'`):

```
$my_regex = str_replace(array("?", "*", "/"), array('\?', "(.*)", '\/'), "/?hl=*&*$");
// $my_regex = str_replace(array("?", "*", "/"), array('\\?', "(.*)", '\\/'), "/?hl=*&*$");
echo $my_regex;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/oLbaqB)

See [this PHP *single-quoted* string literal reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes (the character `'`).
>   To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (`\`). **To specify a literal backslash, double it (`\\`)**. **All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash**: this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as `\r` or `\n`, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

Else, you can use double backslashes within a doubel-quoted string literal ([demo](https://ideone.com/fy9CHx)):

```
$my_regex = str_replace(array("?", "*", "/"), array("\\?", "(.*)", "\\/"), "/?hl=*&*$");
```